# HTML element src attributes sends concatenated string to server

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django

I have a ReactJs and Django project setup. I send a GET request to my localhost for localhost/index, the server running my Django project returns index.html which is correct. The index.html has a  html element with src value "asset/script.js". It sends a request to Locahost/index/asset/script.js instead of Localhost/asset/script.js. Sometimes it sends the first path, sometimes the last path. why?

Debugging, not sure whyt it doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use relative paths in resources. Changing it to `/asset/script.js` (starting with `/`) will make it always load from the root of the URI no matter which page you are on

You can also specify `<base>` for your document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base